# Debian 7, Apache2, PHP w/ FCID - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, debian-wheezy, mpm-worker

A lot of the documentation and search results came from those who have multiple users/sites and not sure if my situation applies to theirs or if it will open it up more than needed.

My situation: Single website and single user. Using Debian 7, Apache2 with mpm-worker, PHP5 with libapache2-mod-fcid.

After installation and reboot, not getting PHP scripts to run.

I enabled the following and it still doesn't work.

```
sudo a2enmod fcid
sudo service apache2 restart
```

What else do I need to change? Also, my installation doesn't seem to have a httpd.conf and only an apache2.conf and security.conf.

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you see error messages in the logs? Does apache respond at all? Are php scripts set to be handled correctly? What documentation are you using to set this up? If you don't have any documentation, you might be better off installing something like VirtualMin on Debian instead, as it handles this stuff for you.

Comment: I modified the VirtualHost file for the fcid and apparently I didn't need to. I reversed my changes and it works fine. Not sure why all those modifications were posted if it works without it.